# Split Elements and their values dynamicaly using xslt1 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

**I want to split these Elements:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CTP>
    <name>ABSA bank</name>
    <BAs>
        <BA>bank</BA>
        <BA>sector</BA>
        <BA>issuer</BA>
    </BAs>
    <altIDs>
        <altID>
            <label.altSystem>ABSB|BBG</label.altSystem>
            <label.altSystem>ASB|Reuters</label.altSystem>
        </altID>
    </altIDs>
</CTP>
```

**into this format:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CTP>
    <name>ABSA bank</name>
    <BAs>
        <BA>bank</BA>
        <BA>sector</BA>
        <BA>issuer</BA>
    </BAs>
    <altIDs>
        <aldID>
            <label>ABSB</label>
            <altSystem>BBG</altSystem>
        </aldID>
        <aldID>
            <label>ASB</label>
            <altSystem>Reuters</altSystem>
        </aldID>
    </altIDs>
</CTP>
```

**im new with Xslt and im trying to solve this exercice, how can we do it in XSLT 1.0?**

**Highlighting the transformed part:**

**Original**

```
<altID>
    <label.altSystem>ABSB|BBG</label.altSystem>
    <label.altSystem>ASB|Reuters</label.altSystem>
</altID>
```

**Transformed**

```
<aldID>
    <label>ABSB</label>
    <altSystem>BBG</altSystem>
</aldID>
<aldID>
    <label>ASB</label>
    <altSystem>Reuters</altSystem>
</aldID>
```

Comment: How is this different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678961/split-xml-element-into-many

Comment: its different because that algorithm is made for creating new elements and not spliting the element and their values and give each part of the element a part of their value. @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), '_')]" name="nest">
        <xsl:param name="name" select="name()" />
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'_'" />
        <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($name, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-before($name, $delimiter)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token" />

                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="{substring-after($name, $delimiter)}">
                    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token" />

                    <!-- recursive call -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="nest">
                        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="substring-after($name, $delimiter)" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```